# Want to remove language from URL, such as redirect abc.com\en\about to abc.com\about

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, sitecore-mvc

I want to redirect abc.com\en\about to abc.com\about.
I have tried adding rules to web config file.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/en/(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Also added rewrite rules and it didn't work.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="RedirectEnglish" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*/en/.*" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

What else can I do to get the above changes on my site?
I added IIS rules, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Why not configure your application such that it does not generate such URLs?

Comment: That is already configured using  <setting   patch:instead="*[@name='Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage']" name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />
but what if the user by any chance hits the url they need to get redirected to the working url

Answer (score 0):

`Rule Pattern` gets the Path string of the URL and doesn’t include the hostname of the server. Therefore, the inbound URL will not match the rule and the rule action will not be performed.
Here is my example.

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^en/(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Alternatively,

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^en/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Result.
[image]

---

[image]
Here is an official explanation of Rewrite module.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.